# Unable to send GET request from Titanium Studio (Android Emulator)

Tags: javascript, dom-events, titanium

I am new in this field. I am working on Android application development. I am using Titanium studio for development. Currently I am working on log in component. I am using following code:

```
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;

var username = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
color:'#336699',
top:10,
left:10,
width:300,
height:40,
hintText:'Username',
keyboardType:Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_DEFAULT,
returnKeyType:Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DEFAULT,
borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
});
win.add(username);

var password = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
color:'#336699',
top:60,
left:10,
width:300,
height:40,
hintText:'Password',
passwordMask:true,
keyboardType:Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_DEFAULT,
returnKeyType:Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DEFAULT,
borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
});
win.add(password);

var loginBtn = Titanium.UI.createButton({
title:'Login',
top:110,
width:90,
height:35,
borderRadius:1,
font:{fontFamily:'Arial',fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:14}
 });
win.add(loginBtn);

var loginReq = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
loginBtn.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
    if (username.value != '' && password.value != '')
{
    loginReq.open("GET","http://localhost:3000");
}
else
{
    alert("Username/Password are required");
}
});
```

But it's not working and not sending GET request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call send() on your HTTPClient

```
loginReq.open("GET","http://localhost:3000");
loginReq.send();
```